# Android + Kotlin + Hilt: [Dagger/MissingBinding] xxx cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method

Tags: android, kotlin, dependency-injection, dagger-2, dagger-hilt

Still digging into the basic concepts of Hilt, and trying to make a simple example to work into my app with no success.

My app is a multi-module app, and apart from the application project (where all the activities are) I have some modules. "Common" is one of them which includes some helpers (for the moment static classes (which I'm trying to migrate to Hilt modules).

For my example, I've picked up the "ExceptionHandler" class (supposedly converted to a Hilt module) and trying to inject it in MainActivity as a field so I can use its methods, like logException, but whatever I try it always ends in a different build error, for example:

CommonModule:

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
class CommonModule {

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideExceptionHandler(): ExceptionHandler {
        return ExceptionHandler
    }
}
```

ExceptionHandler (in Common module):

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object ExceptionHandler {

    fun logException(e: Exception) {
        try {
            if (isOnline) {
                val strException = formatException(e)
                logException(strException)
            }
        } catch (ignored: Exception) {
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

MainActivity:

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity: FragmentActivity(), IActionListeners, IImageListeners, OnListFragmentInteractionListener
{
   @Inject
   lateinit var _exception: ExceptionHandler

    try{
        throw ArithmeticException()
    }catch(ex: Exception){
        _exception.logException(ex)
    }
    ...
}
```

And when I build the app the next error is thrown:

```
/Users/diego/StudioProjects/xxx/app/build/generated/hilt/component_sources/debug/com/xxx/xxx/app/AppSettings_HiltComponents.java:128: error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] exception.ExceptionHandler cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.
public abstract static class SingletonC implements AppSettings_GeneratedInjector,
             ^
exception.ExceptionHandler is injected at
com.xxx.xxx.activities.main.MainActivity._exception
com.xxx.xxx.activities.main.MainActivity is injected at
com.xxx.xxx.activities.main.MainActivity_GeneratedInjector.injectMainActivity(com.xxx.xxx.activities.main.MainActivity) [com.xxx.xxx.app.AppSettings_HiltComponents.SingletonC → com.xxx.xxx.app.AppSettings_HiltComponents.ActivityRetainedC → com.xxx.xxx.app.AppSettings_HiltComponents.ActivityC]
```

BTW, I won't paste Gradle files, manifest an so because Hilt installation is fine.

Comment: Why inject a singleton object when you can access it's function directly:
`ExceptionHandler.logException(ex)` or you can just make `logException(e: Exception)` a global function , either of which you can call from anywhere.

Comment: Thank for your reply @ltp. This is the same question I was always making to myself, if I can call my methods in my static class directly why to use Hilt (or any other dependency injection library) and make my life complicated, but when I asked about having a singleton application class with a context which can be accesible through all activities (like I currently have), and having also all app settings they've told me no, this is not the best practice, this is not testable, and blah blah blah, use DI, and that's why I started to learn Hilt, supposedly to use best practices and do things well.

Comment: I work in C# projects and we have services and repository and such layers injected using DI, and not as classes with static methods, so I'm thinking "why shouldn't I do the same with all my Common module helpers"?

Comment: I'm just testing @ltp and changed the method so it returns any value, like Boolean true, and decorated with Provides decorator, but the same build error: error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] exception.ExceptionHandler cannot be provided without an Provides-annotated method

Comment: You need to separate the object class from the hilt module class. Then provide the object class inside the hilt module.

Answer (score 0):

You provide the dependency class inside the hilt module class.

```
    @Module
    @InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
    class CommonModule{
    
        @Provides
        @Singleton
        fun provideExceptionHandler(): ExceptionHandler {
            return ExceptionHandler
        }
    
    }
```

The dependency

```
 object ExceptionHandler {
      fun logException(e: Exception) {
          try {
            if (isOnline) {
               val strException = formatException(e)
               logException(strException)
            }
         } catch (ignored: Exception) {
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks again for your help @ltp. I've done it exactly as you say in your answer, but the same build error:
Inject
lateinit var common: CommonModule
lateinit var exception: ExceptionHandler
...
exception = common.provideExceptionHandler()
...
exception.logException(ex)
--
error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] exception.CommonModule cannot be provided without an Inject constructor or an Provides-annotated method.

Comment: Why it complains with "...cannot be provided without an Inject constructor or an Provides-annotated method" when there is clearly a Provides in "Common" method?

Comment: Can you add your updated common module in your question?